# PropertyChanged Event Trigger only occurs once

Tags: c#

I Have a base Class that Implements **INPC** named **Bindable** this is my Event

```
    protected void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
    {
        var eventHandler = this.PropertyChanged;
        if (eventHandler != null)
        {
            eventHandler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
    }
```

Everything Works fine but if I have two delegates for my  **PropertyChangedEventHandler**,  only once is fired.

```
public class FirstClass : Bindable
{
    public FirstClass()
    {
        PropertyChanged += Delegate1;
    } 

    Void Delegate1 .... 
}

public class SecondClass : Bindable
{

    private FirstClass _MyFirstClass
    public FirstClass MyFirstClass
    {
        get { return _MyFirstClass; }
        set { SetProperty(ref _MyFirstClass, value); }
    } 

    public SecondClass()
    {
        MyFirstClass = new FirstClass();     
        MyFirstClass.PropertyChanged += Delegate2;
    } 

    Void Delegate2 .... 
}
```

In this simple only **Delegate1** runs **Delegate2** never happens.

How Can I do implment my method properly for trigger any delegate?

**EDIT 1:** Corrected some code and instantiation of Firsrtclass.

**EDIT 2:** Full Implementation

```
public class Bindable : INotifyPropertyChanged //, INotifyPropertyChanging
{
    #region BindableBase
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

   protected bool SetProperty<T>(ref T storage, T value, [CallerMemberName] String propertyName = null)
    {
        if (object.Equals(storage, value)) return false;

        storage = value;
        this.OnPropertyChanged(propertyName);
        return true;
    }

    protected void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
    {
        var eventHandler = this.PropertyChanged;
        if (eventHandler != null)
        {
            eventHandler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
    }
    #endregion

} //    Clase que implementa INotifyPropertyChanged
```

Comment: should not it be `_MyFirstClass.PropertyChanged += Delegate2;`?

Comment: @JleruOHeP That shouldn't matter.

Comment: @JleruOHeP You are ok.. Fixed now... Just some free hand code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that when you create a new instance of FirstClass and set it, the event already fires, before giving you a chance to subscribe to it.

You could move the contents of FirstClass' constructor to a new method and call that method after the events are bound.

Here is your code, fixed:

```
public class FirstClass : Bindable
{
    public void Init()
    {
        PropertyChanged += Delegate1;
        // other stuff 
    } 

    Void Delegate1 .... 
}

public class SecondClass : Bindable
{

    private FirstClass _MyFirstClass
    public FirstClass MyFirstClass
    {
        get { return _MyFirstClass; }
        set { SetProperty(ref _MyFirstClass, value); }
    } 

    public SecondClass()
    {
        MyFirstClass = new FirstClass();     
        MyFirstClass.PropertyChanged += Delegate2;
        MyFirstClass.Init();
    } 

    Void Delegate2 .... 
}
```

Comment: Sorry, doesn't understand. It means something that it is under construction when I'm subsribing to it ?

Comment: Try copy pasting my code. When you assign MyFirstClass, the event already fires. Then you go and ask c# to notify you, but that is already too late. You don't get your handler called for past events! In my example I don't set MyFirstClass right away, I first tell c# to notify me of any events.

Comment: It Is thrwing an error on **MyFirstClass = firstClass;**

Comment: Reference to an object not set as an object instance. :( Sorry don't take care about it. It's my fault. I'm finishing to test.

Comment: Uh, interesting...  Could you edit your post to include the implementation of SetProperty?

Comment: The error was my fault, now fixed. but my problema persists. I'm posting my SetProperty Implementation.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/60931/discussion-between-juan-pablo-gomez-and-sepehr-farshid).

Comment: You are totally Right the problem was JUST ORDER.

Answer (score 1):

Your code is set up wrong for this to run correctly, at all.

If you just instantiate a `FirstClass`, you would expect just `Delegate1` to fire, as no `SecondClass` object was created.

If you instantiate a `SecondClass`, the reference to `FirstClass` is null, so it should throw a `NullReferenceException` right away on the event registration. You need to either create a `FirstClass` when you create a `SecondClass`, or pass `SecondClass` a `FirstClass` instance in its constructor that you can then use to register for the event.

Comment: I'm delegating the event after my FirstClass was created, My code sample was corrected. to show how I'm doing it.

Comment: @JuanPabloGomez Ok, that solves part of the problem. Is the instance whose property is changing the same one that is owned by `SecondClass`?

Comment: Yes it is, I'm expecting to fire In **SecondClass** some extra code "SecondClass" is a view Mode. It has a FirstClass Instance. All my Binds Works great but PropertyChanged doesn't fire on **SecondClass**